# Why "offline" in Object.values(services) is not true when there is "offline" in it

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to know why these behavior exists:

```js
> services = {"test":"offline","test2":"online"}
{ test: 'offline', test2: 'online' }
> Object.values(services)
[ 'offline', 'online' ]
> 'offline' in Object.values(services)
false
```

There is `offline` inside the Array but  I get false with "in" , why ?

And how a "in" like that can be `true` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) looks at properties of an object

```
console.log("make" in { make: "some brand" }) // true
```

Comment: I was just posting the same link :P